# OpenCV 2.4.8 Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, visual-studio-2012, computer-vision

I installed OpenCV 2.4.8 on Visual Studion 2012 (I am a student in CS, so VS is from dreamspark)

I did everything in the installation steps. Then I wrote a simple program to read an image and display it on the screen. When I first compile it, it gives me the error: "The program can't start because opencv_core248d.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.". BUT !!!   When I go to the project folder, and run the .sln file, and THEN compile, IT WORKS! There are no missing dlls, the PATH is created, I saved the property sheets so I don't have to repeat the steps each time. So, why doesn't it compile within the IDE, and yet it does run fine in the second window IDE.

How do I solve this problem.

Comment: I don't know if I understood correctly: are you saying that you run VS 2012 with your project, compile ->run -> missing dll and then you open another instance of VS 2012 and do the same and then it works?

Comment: That is exactly what I'm trying to say - it works after opening the sln file manually and then pressing F5, not the first time.

Comment: Go and post the answer

Answer (score 0):

I SOLVED IT !!! Finally! After you write the directory in your PATH, you have to restart the computer, otherwise VS doesn't know where the dlls are. That's why it works when you open the project manually, and not within the IDE